# Trying to get direct line to point ngrok failing

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

- I have run my bot locally (success)
- I have set ngrok (success)
- I have tested the remote url (success)
- I have added Direct Line webchat to my local running site (success)
- I have set up Direct Line and used this secret in my webchat (success)

However, I still get the old bot response (hosted on Azure)

So I have gone to the bot framework website --> my bot --> settings --> Messaging endpoint  and set the URL as my ngrok address

It seems to be saved, but I get a strange popup saying

> CorrelationID : SHUjnuhs=

Or some other random shortcode.
Seems to be an error from API/botmanager and response to an error 500

Just wondered if there is something else I am missing here in order to get direct line speaking to my locally running bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, that error means that the messaging endpoint has a space at the beginning and so it's not being saved (that's why you are seeing the old message). Reload the page, and before saving make sure there is no space at the begiining of the url.

Comment: I checked that, also checked in the posted json to BotManager and no spaces and json looks fine

Comment: also its worth noting that actually refreshing page, brings back the actual ngrok address, so it must be saved,   does not seem to be saving further down the pipeline

Comment: I refreshed, by doing a total reload, noticed it was not there,  so then tried again and it works now.  So think you may have been right, but the state seems to be stuck so you have empty cache and do a full reload